# One specific application receives "The server was not found or was not accessible" when connecting to DB - all other applications on same machine work

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database application that is run on-premise by many sites, primarily using SQL Express but in some cases using SQL Standard. It has a primary application used for most day-to-day tasks and a few secondary applications, primarily written in C#, to do other things. They all look at a registry key to determine which database to connect to.

At one customer site, all applications bar one (across all machines) are successfully connecting to the database. When the offending application is run, it logs the following error: `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.`

To investigate, we have done a build with extra logging and logged the SQL Server instance it is attempting to connect to, and confirmed that it is the same correct server as all the other applications use. All other applications on the same client machines, including those that use the exact same code to connect to the server, are working fine - they all use the same connection string down to username and password.

Code used to connect:

```
private static SqlConnectionStringBuilder CreatexxConnectionString(string dbName, string sqlInstanceName, int connectionTimeout = 30)
        {
            if (dbName == null)
            {
                dbName = "xxxxx";
            }

            var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.DataSource = sqlInstanceName;
            builder.InitialCatalog = dbName;

            builder.ApplicationName = "xxxxxxxx";
            // override the default to be the specified
            builder.ConnectTimeout = connectionTimeout;

        
            connectionString.UserID = xxxxxx;
            connectionString.Password = xxxxxxx;

            return builder;
        }
```

This occurs at all client machines on the customer's site, everything can connect except this one application, even those that share the same code. Meanwhile this application functions fine everywhere else. We have tried disabling all firewalls on the client and server to test, though this should not really be anything to do with it because the other applications are working. Has anyone seen/been able to fix any kind of similar bug before?

Comment: If you're using instance names in connection strings this requires that clients can use the SQL Server Resolution Protocol to communicate with the SQL Browser Service over udp/1434 to resolve the instance name to the listening TCP port number, then the client attempts to connect to the resolved TCP port number. Sounds like there is a communication issue with the SQL Browser service. Also, the SQL Browser service needs to be restarted after any new instance installations and/or modifications to the SQL Server protocol configurations, because it only enumerates that information when it starts.

Comment: Also consider bittiness... if you're using Aliases from SQL Server client configurations these must be configured for both 32-bit and 64-bit applications. The same client alias name can be configured differently for 32-bit and 64-bit processes, not only connecting to a different target SQL Server but using an entirely different protocol (TCP/IP, Named Pipes, Shared Memory) as well.

Comment: There appears to be a random Alias in there so we will try removing this tonight and resetting the SQL Browser service, however if this were affecting it shouldn't the problems be happening for everything? All affected applications are unfortunately 32-bit.